# Every finite closed cover is fundmental?

Tags: general-topology

Before I ask the question, here's how fundamental covers are defined:

> A cover $\{C_i\}$ of a topological space $X$ is fundamental if: $A$ is open in $X$ *iff* $A \cap C_i$ is open in $C_i$ for all $i$, where the $C_i$s have the subspace topology.

It's not very hard to show that open covers are fundamental. What I'm stuck on is how to show that every finite closed cover is fundamental. I'd be much obliged if someone could give me a pointer or two in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: One direction is trivial. For the other, suppose that $\{C_1,\ldots,C_n\}$ is a closed cover of $X$, and that $U\subseteq X$ is such that $U\cap C_k$ is open in $C_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$. Show that

$$U=X\setminus\bigcup_{k=1}^n(C_k\setminus U)\;,$$

and that this set is open in $X$.